# Angular full calender init issue on tab click

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular7

I am working on angular7 project and having the issue with full calendar.
I want to show the calendar on tabs but angular full calendar is not initialize on tab active. 
please refer the following screenshot
[image]

I am using material tab https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview and for full calendar i have integrated https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular this.

Code

appointment-Calendar.Component.ts

```
 export class AppointmentCalendarComponent implements OnInit {

        @ViewChild('calendar', {static: true}) calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; // the #calendar in the template


        calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin];
        calendarWeekends = true;

       calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [{"title":"Dr. Helen Jones 07:20 PM","start":"2019-07-31 19:20:00"},{"title":"Dr. Jonathan 07:20 PM","start":"2019-08-07 19:20:00"}];


      constructor() { }

       ngOnInit() {}


    }
```

Appointments.component.ts

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTab" [disableRipple]="true" animationDuration="0ms">
        <mat-tab label = "List View"> 
             <app-appointment-listing (selectTab)="getOutputval($event)" ></app-appointment-listing>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label = "Calendar">
           <app-appointment-calendar (selectTab)="getOutputval($event)"></app-appointment-calendar> 
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

appointment-calendar.component.html

```
<div class="card card-box">
   <div class="card-box-content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12 text-right btn-wrap margin-btm20">
            <a [routerLink]="['/appointment/create']" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <full-calendar
            #calendar
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            [header]="{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            }"
            [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
            [weekends]="calendarWeekends"
            [events]="calendarEvents"
            (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
            ></full-calendar>   
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest

Comment: can you please share your code to better understand how you have integrated the tabs and fullcalendar in your application ?

Comment: Thanks for interest in my post !! I have shared the code

Comment: please share the appointment-Calendar.Component.html script

Comment: shared the appointment-calendar.component.html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the investigation I found that this issue is related to css. So I just put the .fc-widget-content .fc-scroller {height: auto !important;} in style.css and resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue just fix the following points.

1. Install correct plugins

   *npm install --save @fullcalendar/timegrid @fullcalendar/interaction*
2. Import in your appointment-Calendar.Component.ts file

   *import timeGrid from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';*

   *import interaction from '@fullcalendar/interaction';*
3. Update your calendarPlugins list with the following :

   *calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrid, interaction];*

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I tried as per your suggestion but still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of fullcalender. Fullcalender won't render the calendar when it is not visible. The only solution is to manually render calendar on tab change event.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render

Answer (score 0):

For me I made the fullCalenar html tag with `ngIf="selectedIndex = 1"` and I added in constructor `this.calendar?.getApi()?.updateSize()` to update size while initializing component

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue with Angular 16 + PrimeNG tabs. The root cause of the issue is that FullCalendar has a feature it won't render itself when it is not visible. Using it on a tab makes it "not visible" in that exact moment the calendar tries to render itself. To overcome it, I found only a bit dirty solution, where I call render after view initialization is done. I have a wrapper over the FullCalendar component, this wrapper is on every tab, like this:

```
<p-tabView #tabView [(activeIndex)]="activeIndex">
    <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [header]="item.name">
      <ng-container *ngIf="tabView.activeIndex === i">
        <calendar-wrapper [id]="item.id" [calendarOptions]="calendarOptions[i]"></calendar-wrapper>
      </ng-container>
    </p-tabPanel>
  </p-tabView>
```

And in the calendar-wrapper there is a calendarObject (ViewChild reference) wrapped into a setTimeout to pull it out of the flow, making sure it is called when the calendar is visible already:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.fCalendarObjects?.getApi().render();
    }, 1);
}
```

This 1 millisecond is not visible to the user, but just enough to have in the context stack properly.